# What is the difference between --disable-features=site-per-process and --disable-features=SitePerProcess?

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I would like to know if there is any difference between the following settings for Chromium options.

`--disable-features=site-per-process`

`--disable-features=SitePerProcess`

I have been using `--disable-features=site-per-process` to be able to specify an element in an iframe and get a selector.　However, it no longer worked well in Puppeteer version 19.8.0, so I tried `--disable-features=SitePerProcess` and it works now.　Hopefully it will work the same in all versions.